# Accessing HttpClient in multiple tasks causes "The request was canceled" exceptions

Tags: c#, async-await

I am creating an application that consumes REST API's. I wrapped the HTTP calls in a class like this. There are many similar methods in this class. I reuse the same HttpClient instance for all methods, as StackOverflow answers said it was meant to be reused and designed thread-safe.

```
public async Task<DataType> GetData()
{
    var address = "XXX";
    var res = await Client.GetAsync(address).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var data = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return data;
}
```

I use timers to call API's regularly (each timer calls a different API). When there is only one timer, the programme seems to run well. But when there are two timers, `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException` keeps happening at the second line.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'
Inner Exception
WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled
```

Inner trace:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Outer trace:

```
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

What does it mean the request was cancelled? It is not related to the web server side, right? Do I need to take care of something when calling HttpClient in multiple threads (`Task`s)?

**Update**

After seeing the traffic with an HTTP analyser, I found that the same HTTP requests (which supposed to be made only once at a time) were made very many at once. I started the task at a selection changed event of a third-party UI control. And for some reason, the UI control raised selection changed events very quickly when actually the selection was not changed. I am investigating the cause, and if that is the reason, I may have to close this question.

**Update 2**

I found out a way to suppress those redundant selection changed events and now the exception does not occur. I tried to delete the question, but the warning said that Stack Overflow did not recommend doing so, and if I kept doing it, I might be blocked from Stack Overflow. Closing options did not fit the real reason, so I will leave this. It might be helpful to someone with similar problems in the future.

Comment: Try changing the value of HttpCompletionOption to ResponseContentRead (if its not already)

Answer (score 4):

You should **not** call the `.Result` instead

```
public async Task<DataType> GetData()
{
    var address = "XXX";
    var res = await Client.GetAsync(address).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var data = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return data;
}
```

The issue here is you are offloading the `await` on the first `async (ConfigureAwait(false))` but then calling `.Result` on the second. I can't tell without seeing the rest of the application but you maybe deadlocking on the `.Result` call.

[**Stephan Cleary's**: Article on why you shouldn't block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: At first the method in the class did not use await, but just used `Result`. When using two tasks, deadlock happened. I read the very article, and changed it to await/ConfigureAwait(false), but I forgot to change the second one (`ReadAsStringAsync`). Anyways, the exception still happens after the change, and I do not think it is a deadlock. When deadlock happened, the method simply did not return. This time, it throws an exception. Can there be other possible problems?